# ImportError for pyinstaller-packed PyCharm project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pyinstaller, python-module

**Problem:** I have a Python3 project using Anaconda and PyCharm which runs fine from within PyCharm.

When building a deployable version using pyinstaller, the building process seems to work, but the generated .exe file crashes with the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "code\main.py", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'code.libs'; 'code' is not a package`

**Details:**
main.py:10 states `from code.libs.hugelib.important import ImportantClass`

The directory structure looks like (all init.py are empty):

`code/
   __init__.py
   libs/
      __init__.py
      hugelib/
         __init__.py
         important.py
         whatever.py
      stuff.py
   main.py
data/`

I create the executable using `code>pyinstaller main.spec`
main.spec has been created using `--paths=libs --paths=code --paths=code/libs --hidden-import=code  --hidden-import=code.libs`

**Question:** Why is 'code' not seen as a package, even if the init files are there, and why is PyCharm executing everything just fine, while pyinstaller's bundled version is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the module was named "code", this seems to be a python-internal name/module already and pyinstaller got confused over it